# How to create html page dynamically from flash?

Tags: php, html, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a flash movie with a button to 'view items in new browser window.'

These items are all dynamically generated in flash.
So the html has to be dynamically generated as well.

Can any sugest a way to do this?
Do I need to use php or some server side script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean "in new browser window." , then all you need to do is something like

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.yoursite.com/somePage.php?content=hi_there"), "_blank");
```

where the http://www.yoursite.com/somePage.php contains dynamically generated content from the querystring ( say... retrieve the content "hi there" from the example above) using PHP/server side script

if you mean "html content generated INSIDE flash", then you can use FlashML http://osflash.org/flashml  (seems to be actionscript 2 tho )

if you mean "html like content in Flash", then you can write script to form your own content inside flash, like dynamically putting movieclips together to make it like a html page

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bad practice to generate it all from within flash. I reckon the most common solution would be to pass only the generated data to a server script or js method that replicates the way items shows up in flash but in HTML for instance.

Comment: Be careful with passing content to the server and getting the server to execute it! This can easily be used by evil doers (code injection).

Comment: Definitely, that's why i would only pass pure data so the remote method could moderate it. Generating the whole content from within flash would just be a big security hole since the remote would be forced to publish it blindely. Good point to emphasize though!

Answer (score 0):

Use a hybrid of Javascript AND Flash. So Flash triggers the function for the Javascript to do the DOM/HTML manipulation.

In flash you will call the *External* library to pass some **essential** parameters to the JS.

it goes like this in AS3:

```
import flash.external.*;
...
ExternalInterface.call("JavascriptFunctionName", escape(param1), escape(param2));
```

In JavaScript:

```
JavascriptFunctionName = function(_param1, _param2){
 CreateHTMLElement(unescape(_param1));
 CreateMenuItem(unescape(_param2));
}
```

If you are passing a lot of data, I'd suggest using a php proxy/webservice.